# Signing problem with own apt repository

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, signature, reprepro

I want to create an own repository for our application.
I created a master key with signing subkey with pgp before and I sign the deb package with:

```
dpkg-sig --sign builder sample.deb
```

Then I create the repo with reprepro:

```
reprepro --ask-passphrase -b base includedeb all sample.deb
```

Reprepro creates the necessary signed files:

```
./conf:
distributions  options

./db:
checksums.db  contents.cache.db  packages.db  references.db  release.caches.db  version

./dists:
all

./dists/all:
InRelease  main  Release  Release.gpg

./dists/all/main:
binary-amd64  binary-i386

./dists/all/main/binary-amd64:
Packages  Packages.gz  Release

./dists/all/main/binary-i386:
Packages  Packages.gz  Release

./pool:
main

./pool/main:
s

./pool/main/s:
sample

./pool/main/s/sample:
sample_2.2.48.9015_all.deb
```

I install the public key on client machine but after installing package I receive this message:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  sample
Install these packages without verification? [y/N]
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

GPG signing is complicated. For APT repositories there are two layers of GPG signatures:

1. Signatures on the packages themselves, with `dpkg-sig` or or `debsign`.
2. Signatures on the repository metadata.

You are seeing that message because APT does not see any signature on your repository metadata. You can make this happen by adding `SignWith` to your reprepro config. You can read more in a comprehensive blog post I wrote, [here](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2014/10/28/howto-gpg-sign-verify-deb-packages-apt-repositories/).

You can verify that `SignWith` has worked by looking for a file named `Release.gpg` or `InRelease`. If you find a file named `InRelease`, view the contents of the file and ensure that a GPG signature is found at the bottom. If so, reprepro has generated the signature properly. Keep in mind that repositories that are GPG signed are still vulnerable to a large number of man-in-the-middle attacks unless they are served over HTTPS.

I would also recommend checking that the public GPG key has been correctly imported on the client system by running `apt-key list`. If you don't see the key on the list, you should add it with `apt-key add filename`.

It is important to note that Ubuntu and Debian do not verify GPG signatures of packages -- it is disabled by default and terribly, terribly difficult to get working. I would advise avoiding GPG signing your packages.

Also note that you should distribute your repository over HTTPS, to avoid a plethora of security bugs (even with GPG signatures).

Comment: I have SignWith tag in the distributions file, but no success. You advised "avoiding GPS signing", and then? How to avoid warning messages?

Comment: I updated my answer, you should re-read it. You are signing packages with dpkg-sig -- package signatures are never verified, so you can stop doing that. The SignWith is enough -- you need to check if reprepro has generated a signature and if it has, you should check on the client machine that the key was properly imported.